# How can I know required data for later steps in SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, testing, specflow

My problem is the following:

Some of my scenarios need to save the state of my model after it was loaded to compare it later. I would do it with serializing the objects and compare them later in the test. But I do not want to serialize the state in every test - this could have a negative impact on the performance of the tests. How can I know if this data is necessary?

I thought of using tags, but this is an information which should be hidden from the feature file. I do not want to be forced to write something like `@SaveInitialState` over every test where I need it.

**EDIT**

Here one sample test which needs the information

```
Given I have loaded some model
When I do some action
And Undo the last action
Then The loaded model is unchanged
```

Serialization is here the chosen way because the model has no possibility to be cloned and I do not want to introduce new production code for the tests. The serialization can be done in the tests only.

Comment: Adding sample of tests to question would be great. Also it's not clear why you have to use serialization

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to do the wrong kind of testing here or at least to use the wrong tool for this kind of testing.

[Specflow](http://specflow.org) is a tool that is designed in what is commonly known as [BDD](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) but is more accurately called [Specification By Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_by_example). The basic idea of this is that you **provide concrete examples** of interesting cases that will test the functionality of your application.

These examples need to be explicit. Saying something like `Then the loaded model is unchanged` is very implicit. Instead I would use a case like.

```
Given I am editing Bob's details
When I change Bob's age to 42
And I undo all changes
Then Bob should be aged 24
```

Please note, I am using a trick here of using a pre-defined example. The idea is that all developers and BAs on the team knows that Bob is 24 yrs old and works on the helpdesk. You have defined that known example upfront simply so you can avoid saying

```
Given I create a new Person
And my person should be called Bob
And my person should be aged 24
And my person should work on the Help desk
```

Comment: If the data is more complex than just a person object. For example a graphical worksheet with ten and more objects which are connected to each other and aligned in a certain way. It can be confusing to describe in detail what needed to be undone after a complex action.

Comment: Again using a predefined example can really simplfy this, e.g.
`Given I'm editing the Gordon Ramsey Duck a l'orange workflow`, that should certainly have more than ten steps some of which occur in parallel. It's really about painting the picture of what somebody reading the spec should see :-)

Comment: If have not the problem to load the examples but to verify an action and that it is undone. One action I am testing for example modifies one property of 5 objects and creates 5 new objects. I would need to check if the five properties are reset and that non of the five objects exists. That would make the test really confusing.